# Difference between Date column and other date

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to find difference between Date column in spark dataset and date value which is not column.

If both were column i would do

datediff(col("dateStart"),col("dateEnd")

As i want to find difference between col("dateStart") and another date which is not column

val dsWithTimeDiff = detailedRecordsDs.withColumn(RunDate, 
                     lit(runDate.toString))

```
val dsWithTimeDiff = dsWithRunDate.withColumn(DateDiff,
  datediff(to_date(col(RunDate)), col(DateCol)))
```

Is there better way to do instead of adding one more column and then finding difference

Comment: You don't have to add the column to your dataframe, you can use the literal column directly: `datediff(to_date(lit(runDate.toString)), col(DateCol))`